# Feature to draw attention to answered, yet unsolved questions, other than by bounty

Tags: feature-request

I guess, this concerns every stackexchange site.

It sometimes happens that I ask a question which is answered, but not satisfactorily. I then have the option to put a bounty on this question. But I made the experience (on another stackexchange) that even then there will be no satisfactory answer.

I think it would be a good idea to add a button for “Unaccepted” answers in the “Unanswered” section. Or – since there are users just don't accept answers out of laziness or something – it might be even better to allow users to explicitly mark their questions as “unsolved” or “unaccepted”. That way they still have a chance to get some (permanent) attention which is needed for them to be solved by someone.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a question where this might help? We do quite well answering questions, and you tend to wonder about the question itself if there is no good answer.

Comment: @JosephWright The ones I asked where I didn't accept an answer, viz: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80264/list-environment-to-set-different-paragraphs-within-an-item) and [that one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79194/misplaced-qed-symbol-after-displaymath-inside-item-of-inline-list). But I'll try and bump them by editing them as suggested by lockstep. Have you seen my questions and found they were ill-stated or did you just assume I don't put enough effort in asking them? (Hope this doesn't come out too harsh, I'm really wondering.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If *"a question [...] is answered, but not satisfactorily"*, you have also the option to edit the question and explain why none of the answers given so far is satisfactory enough to accept it. (This assumes that at least one of the answers was useful enough to earn an upvote; otherwise, the question would be considered "unanswered", which definitely draws attention.) This sort of editing is a legitimate way to "bump" a question (bring it to the front page again).

With regard to your proposed "unaccepted" marker, I fail to see how this is different from *simply not marking any answer as accepted*. (Note that it is possible to search for questions without accepted answers; e.g., a [search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbiblatex%5D%20hasaccepted:0) for `[biblatex] hasaccepted:0` returns 255 questions.)

Comment: I did not know you can search like this. (The idea of an "unaccepted" marker was to filter out those questions whose questioner is _definitely_ not satisfied by answers so far as opposed to those questions where the questioner simply didn't care to accept.)

Comment: @K.Stm.: See this post about [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](http://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: @Werner Thanks, I already looked it up.